# Meaning of got in a sentence

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of **got** in the following sentence?

> Even when it voted in 2012 in favour of a credible investigation into human rights, India had **got** the resolution to incorporate the need for Sri Lanka’s ‘concurrence’ to any assistance that the Office of the High Commissioner for Human Rights may offer in such a probe.

I looked for different meanings of **got** in Oxford Dictionary but none of those meanings suits my sentence and I am unable to understand.

Comment: Source of the quote, please.

Answer (score 0):

"Got" is a widely used and overused word.  But here it has the meaning extendend only a little from "received": India "received" this clause from the people writing the resolution.

You could also say that India "achieved" this. We can say, in a simpler example

> I got my son to comb his hair.

Meaning that my target was for my son to comb his hair, and I achieved that target.